# but I knew before I went that I didn't really want > to have a serious relationship with Joe

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, clauses

Can we use "know that" in the following way?

Is it kind of a grammar rule to put an independent clause between "verb + that"?

> It was a really terrible vacation. It was my fault. I mean I wanted to go to Thailand, but I **knew** *before I went* **that** I didn't really want to have a serious relationship with Joe. And the vacation just showed me how different we are.

Comment: Isn't that a dependent clause there?

Comment: I know before I go that I will have to ask you a question.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is OK. For a better "flow" I would use the following:

> It was a really terrible vacation. It was my fault. I mean, I wanted to go to Thailand, *but I knew **even** before **going there** that* I didn't really want to have a serious relationship with Joe. And the vacation just showed me how different we are.